# GLSL code to 2D terrain with height map rendering

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml

I have a 2d tile based map and image of height map, which I would like to use to make map look less flat. But I am new to GLSL which is used in SFML. I am looking for some GLSL shader to which I can pass tile texture and part of height map on the same coordinates or something to create height illusion. But I am doing everything by myself and I dont have time to learn GLSL just for this one shader I would like to use, so thanks for any reply (best would be if someone could post some shader code and explaint it for dummies how is it used in .cpp file)

Comment: "I dont have time to learn GLSL just for this" is not likely to get you far, since it's unlikely that someone will write all the code for you, including shader bindings, based on a rather vague description. However, to give you some ideas: Shading higher ground lighter will give a cheap AO approximation that kind of gives a depth impression. Using dFdx/dFdy you can get an estimate of where the normal of the terrain points to. Settle for a light vector for the sun, and take the dot product. That makes the hill sides which face the "sun" brighter, also giving an illusion of depth.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably interested in the technique ["Parallax Occlusion Mapping"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax_mapping). A good implementation can be found [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/562481-parallax-occlusion-mapping-in-glsl/).

Comment: thanks that is nice example. I read some GLSL tutorials but I still dont understand what should I pass to that shader. I need to initialize every glogal variable that is defined in GLSL code?

Comment: You need to set the following variables: uniform mat4 matView;
uniform mat3 matViewProjection;

uniform float fHeightScale;
uniform float fPerspectiveBias;
uniform vec4 vLightOffset;

Comment: It should be noted that in a 2D tile-based rendering, parallax occlusion mapping is not really of much use. 2D tile-based implies "top down" view, in which case the parallax is zero. Though one might use the self-occlusion term that is often calculated together with POM. This will give some impression of depth.

Comment: Unless you set it to a specified value, so that you always look from the same "angle".

Answer (score 0):

This will kick the Z on the screen to give the illusion of a height map.
It does not actually change the geometry.
[edit] This is not useful for top down view.. Id try adding some sort of shadow effect based on the new Z and a light direction.

This line: **pos.z +=  color.x + color.y + color.z;** is what pushes the Z. You can give scale a positive or negative number.

```
/* Vertex Program
 * Shifts Z by Textures color     
 */
uniform sampler2D color_texture;
uniform float scale;
varying vec4 p_color;
void main()
{
     vec2 texcoords = gl_MultiTexCoord0.st;
     p_color = texture2D(color_texture,texcoords);
     vec4 color = texture2D(color_texture,texcoords);
     vec4 pos = gl_Vertex;
     pos.z +=  color.x + color.y + color.z;
     pos.z*=scale;
   gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * pos;
}
```

And here is the VERY simple Fragment program..

```
/* Fragment Program
   Copies incoming fragment color without change.
*/
varying vec4 p_color;
 void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = p_color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This deforms the a terrain mesh with a bubble/dome shape base where ever the light is in world space. The more the terrain is tessellated the better the results.

```
Const Float PI = 3.1415928;
vec3 vVertex = vec3( gl_Vertex);
float d = distance(lightPos , gl_Vertex);
float d2;
    if (d < 1500.0)
    {
    d2 = d/1500.0;
    d = cos(PI*2.0*d2);
    }
    else
    {
    d=0.0;
    d2=0.0;
    }
vVertex.y += (d*75.0)*(1.0-d2)-50.;

gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix* vec4(vVertex,gl_Vertex.w);
```